# AWS CLI cp doesn't copy the files second time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to `copy/move/sync` the files from local directory to S3 using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

I was able to successfully upload files for the very first time to the S3 bucket but when I try to run the same command again for uploading the second time it fails to upload. The command doesn't throw any error.

Here is the command which I ran for moving the files.

`aws s3 mv --recursive my-directory s3://my-files/`

For instance, I had files `file1.pdf`, `file2.pdf` and `file3.pdf`.

If I delete `file2.pdf` from the s3 bucket and try to copy the file again using `cp` or `sync` or `mv`. It won't be uploading the file back again to s3 bucket.

AWS CLI Version: `aws-cli/1.15.10 Python/2.6.6 Linux/2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64 botocore/1.10.10`

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "uploading the second time"? The `mv` command copies the files, then deletes them. (It does not delete the directories, it only deletes the files.) If you were to run it a second time, there are no files to move, so nothing happens -- this should be expected. Or did you put new files in `my-directory` before running the command again?

Comment: I have been using `cp`, `mv` & `sync` to have the file updates between the s3 and my local. I have deleted a bunch of files from the s3 bucket. When I try to `cp` files back again it would run the command successfully but doesn't copy/upload anything to s3.

Comment: That's different to what you're asking in the question. Feel free to Edit the question and provide a simplified example of what's happening. Preferably, try to reproduce the problem with a minimal example that we can try to reproduce and diagnose. Also, make sure you're using the latest version of aws-cli just to be sure. (At the time of writing, it appears to be aws-cli/1.15.10)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I had updated my question giving more specific examples and added the AWS CLI version details.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy the file again"? If you run `mv`, it copies the file and then **deletes the local file**. If you try to move/copy it again, it isn't available locally, so there is nothing to move/copy.

Comment: I ran the `mv` command initially which just deleted the files but I still have the folders as it is which I pretended that the files exist in these folders but there aren't. That's the reason when I run the `cp` & `sync` commands it wasn't working. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I ran the `aws s3 mv --recursive my-directory s3://my-files/` which transfers the files and deletes them from the local directory. Only the files were deleted, folders still exist. Files didn't exist in those folders so the subsequent `cp` & `sync` commands didn't work.